# Python group list by same numbers

Tags: python, list, sequence

I need help with python function, which will count for me how many repeated numbers on list, if they are separated by another number.

```
nums = [3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

should return

```
{
[3]: 2,
[1]: 3,
[2]: 5,
[1, 1]: 2,
[2, 2, 2, 2]: 1
}
```

Comment: You could keep track of the current streak and set the corresponding dictionary value(s) to + 1.

Comment: I don't think you can have a list as a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to collect the consecutive numbers and `collections.Counter` to count them:

```
nums = [3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]

from itertools import groupby
from collections import Counter
dict(Counter(tuple(g) for k,g in groupby(nums)))
```

**NB. You cannot use lists as dictionary keys, I've used tuples instead**

Output:

```
{(3,): 2,
 (1,): 3,
 (2,): 5,
 (1, 1): 2,
 (2, 2, 2, 2): 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot have a list as a key. Instead, we can use a string.

This returns all lengths of streaks, not just max and min. Say in comments if you would like otherwise.

```
nums = [3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
results = {}
streak = 0
previous = None
for num in nums:
    print(num)
    if previous != num:
        streak = 0
    streak += 1
    previous = num
    for i in range(1, streak + 1):
        results[str(num)*i] = results.get(str(num)*i, 0) + 1
```

Please comment if you would like an explanation.

Comment: i see, good idea with code, thanks! but its count many variants of this nums...and my point is not to break the order.  like mozway done.